# Defining a boolean simple array type

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying to define a type for Boolean simple-arrays.  This should be easy enough:

```
(deftype boolean-vector (&optional (length '*))
  "Simple vector of BOOLEAN elements."
  `(simple-array boolean (,length)))
```

yet:

```
CL-USER> (typep #(nil nil t t t) 'boolean-vector)
T
CL-USER> (typep #(nil nil t t 5) 'boolean-vector)
T
CL-USER> (typep 5 'boolean)
NIL
```

Anyone have any ideas why this `deftype` isn't doing what it's supposed to and how to properly define a vector type that contains only elements of type `boolean`?

**Answer**
Two good explanations appear below.  What I ended up doing:

```
(defun boolean? (object)
  "Check type of OBJECT is BOOLEAN."
  (typep object 'boolean))

(defun boolean-sequence-p (x)
  (every #'boolean? x))

(deftype simple-boolean-vector (&optional (length '*))
  "Vector of BOOLEAN elements."
  `(and (simple-array * (,length))
    (satisfies boolean-sequence-p)))
```

Comment: That tries to define a type using runtime data. How useful is it?

Comment: Well, the problem I'm trying to solve is that I'm given an array of Boolean types, and it's not under my control to ask for a bit vector.  I need to dispatch on the type, thus the need to define a type for etypecase.

Comment: @CL-USER: that's actually a good use of this!  I was trying to think of one...  Of course it means `typecase` will be slow in general.

Answer (score 3):

`deftype` is doing what it is supposed to do, but

```
> (upgraded-array-element-type 'boolean)
t
```

In other words there is no specialised array type which can hold only `t` and `nil`: you can't have an array which can hold *only* `boolean`s in your implementation.  Of course it is possible that an implementation could support such a thing but I think it would be extraordinarily unlikely.

If you want an array type which can hold only true or false values then you probably want `bit-vectors` which [are required to exist](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/15_abb.htm), with some wrappers.  For instance:

```
(deftype array-index ()
  `(integer 0 (,array-dimension-limit)))

(defun make-boolean-vector (n &key (initial-element nil))
  (declare (type array-index n)
           (type boolean initial-element))
  (make-array (list n) :element-type  'bit :initial-element (if initial-element 1 0)))

(declaim (inline bref (setf bref)))


(defun bref (v n)
  (declare (type bit-vector v)
           (type array-index n))
  (= (bit v n) 1 t nil))

(defun (setf bref) (b v n)
  (declare (type bit-vector v)
           (type array-index n)
           (type boolean b))
  (setf (bit v n) (if b 1 0))
  b)
```

Comment: Symbolics Genera: (upgraded-array-element-type 'boolean) -> (member t nil)

Comment: @RainerJoswig: that's impressive.  It's a long time since I had a machine running Genera: does it enforce this and is the the `array-element-type` of arrays with declared element-type `boolean` right?  If so I wonder *how* it enforces it: `nil` is pretty magic obviously but `t` is just a symbol.  Perhaps arrays have some kind of associated hook function?

Comment: The array element type is `(member t nil)`. When one stores a true value (everything not `nil`), then this gets stored as `T`. The array storage is optimized accordingly.

Comment: @RainerJoswig So `(eql (progn (setf (aref a n) x) (aref a n)) x)` can be false?  If that's true then, well, yuk.

Comment: `(eql 'T some-true-value)` can also be NIL, so the problem is not new.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: that's not the problem I am talking about.  If I store a value in an element of an array I would like the system either to signal an error if the array cannot hold objects of that type, or to store it, and *then give me the same value when I read the same element of the array*, not some other different value which happens to have the same truthiness.  I expect it will turn out that nothing in the spec actually requires this of course.  Anyway.

Comment: I would not care. `(setf (aref digit-char-p-vector 0) (digit-char-p #\3))` -> I would be happy enough if it stores a T in a boolean vector.

Comment: So what would an implementation have to do to support this? It doesn't seem like it would be *too* much effort for a single implementation to support as an extension.

Comment: @CL-USER: Implementations *do* support arrays of booleans: they just call them arrays of bits.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(defun bool-array (a)
  (and (simple-array-p a)
       (every (lambda (e) (typep e 'boolean)) a)))

(deftype boolean-vector ()
  `(satisfies bool-array))
```

Test:

```
> (typep #(nil nil t t t) 'boolean-vector)
T

> (typep #(nil nil t t 5) 'boolean-vector)
NIL

> (typep 5 'boolean-vector)
NIL
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that something like this is just insane: `(defun foo (a) (declare (type boolean-vector a)) (g a) ... now A may or may not be a boolean-vector))`